# Validate x509 Certificate Path C#

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate, x509, pkix

I am getting x509certificate2 from signed XML document. And then I need to validate certificate path,but for that I need 3 certificates : root,CA,end. How to make that ? Certificate is from e-ID card.(that's from Armenian Government,so it is trusty anchor) Revocation Status is good,but can't build certificate path. I wrote like this,but don't know if it's right or not,because it throws an exception on

*var pkixResult = certPathValidator.Validate(certPath, paramsPkix);*

**$exception {"Trust anchor for certification path not found."} Org.BouncyCastle.Pkix.PkixCertPathValidatorException**

```
public static PkixCertPathValidatorResult Validate_Pkix(SignatureDocument signatureDocument)
        {
            var signingCertificate = signatureDocument.XadesSignature.GetSigningCertificate();
            X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
            chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
            chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

            chain.Build(signingCertificate);


            var sigCert = signingCertificate.ToBouncyX509Certificate();
            var issuer = chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate;
            var client = chain.ChainElements[1].Certificate;
            var final = chain.ChainElements[2].Certificate;


            //-----------------

            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate clientCert = client.ToBouncyX509Certificate();
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate issuerCert = issuer.ToBouncyX509Certificate();
            Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate finalCert = chain.ChainElements[2].Certificate.ToBouncyX509Certificate();

            var x509Certs = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();

            x509Certs.Add(sigCert);
            x509Certs.Add(clientCert);
            x509Certs.Add(finalCert);

            IX509Store x509CertStore = X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", new X509CollectionStoreParameters(x509Certs));


            var certPath = new PkixCertPath(x509Certs);

            ISet trust = new HashSet { new TrustAnchor(x509Certs[0], null) };

            var certPathValidator = new PkixCertPathValidator();

            var paramsPkix = new PkixParameters(trust);
            paramsPkix.AddStore(x509CertStore);
            paramsPkix.IsRevocationEnabled = false;

            var pkixResult = certPathValidator.Validate(certPath, paramsPkix);

            return pkixResult;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Root CA certificate to the `x509Certs`.
If that is not part of the signature document you can use the AIA extensions to try downloading it, or use the windows store - as you say the root is trusted.

So load the root from the [X509Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=net-5.0).

As an alternative you could use the [X509Chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain?view=net-5.0) which uses the windows trust store by default and also validates chain and revocation status.

Comment: If X509Chain does that,so I dont need to write this code , Yes?